# Decoding Morse from a blinking light

Tags: opencv, image-processing, c++-cli, emgucv

I'm trying to decode Morse from a blinking light.
I have a camera that is looking at a light source, and the light source is blinking a certain letter or message in Morse Code.

I'm trying to count the number of frames that the light is on, and depending on that number, then it's a dot or dash. While the light is blinking I'm outputting whether it's a dot or dash to a textbox on the user interface, and then after I haven't received any blinks in a while, then it's safe to assume that's the end of the message so I can output the entire message into the text box.

For now I'm only doing letters, no complex messages yet, and it only works SOME of the time.
Problems that seem to occur randomly are

1. it's saying its a dot when it's a dash,
2. after it outputs the letter to the text box, it won't recognize any consequent dots or dashes.

How could I fix the above problems? And also I was wondering if anyone had some tips how to make this code more efficient?

Below is the code I have now. I'm using a 60fps(or so it says) camera, VS2010, with Emgu CV

```
int led_on = 0;
    for(int i = x; i < height; i+=pixeljump)
    {
        for(int j = y; j< width; j+=pixeljump)
        {
            byte a = frameColorDisplay->Data[i,j,0]; //once i find the first spot of light, I'm only concerned with the pixels in the i
            if(a > 225){                             //in the immediate vicinity because the camera and the light source are stationary
                frameOn++;
                frameOff = 0;
                led_on = 1;
                x = i;
                y = j;
                pixeljump = 1;
                height = i + 10;
                width = j + 10;
                //tbMorse->Text = "I see the light";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(led_on == 0){
        frameOff++;
    }

    if((frameOff > 15) && ((frameOn > 15) && (frameOn <=25))){      //if the number of frames the light is on is between 15 and 25, its a dot
        tbMorse->Text = "That's a dot";
        //tbMorse->Text=String::Format("{0:F}",frameOn);
        Morse+= ".";
        frameOn = 0;
        frameOff = 0;
        signalreceived = 1;
    }else if((frameOff > 15) && (frameOn > 25)){                    //if it's greater than 25, it's a dash
        tbMorse->Text = "That's a dash";
        //tbMorse->Text=String::Format("{0:F}",frameOn);
        Morse+= "-";
        frameOn = 0;
        frameOff = 0;
        signalreceived = 1;
    }
 if((frameOff > 60) && (signalreceived == 1)){ //if it's off for a full second, its safe to send the message
        text += Morse2Text(Morse);
        String ^managedString = marshal_as<String^>( text );
        //String ^managedString = marshal_as<String^>( Morse );
        tbMorse->Text = managedString;
        text.clear();
        Morse.clear();
        signalreceived = 0;
        frameOn = 0;
        frameOff = 0;
    }
```

and these are my declarations of global variables

```
 int frameOn = 0;
int frameOff = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int pixeljump = 25;
int height;
int width;
int signalreceived = 0;
string Morse;
string text; 
string Morse2Text(string morse);
```

Height and Width are initialized to the height and width of the frame initially.
The Morse2Text function takes in a string of dots and dashes, goes through a massive block of if statements to see what the dots and dashes correspond to, and returns the alphabet value of the dots and dashes.

Comment: well my first suggestion will be to count the time passed(milliseconds) insted of the number of frames.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would really help, seeing as I'm only checking for the light when I'm grabbing a frame, and seeing as the frame rate is 60 fps, the time would be updated every 1/60 of a second. Could you explain why counting the time passed would be advantageous? @DimaMaligin

Comment: are you sure that your program can handle 60 fps?
maybe by the time you processed the first frame your cam is already on the 20th. maybe you cam missed a few frames for what ever reason(there are plenty). if you check by time since last frame processed itll be more accurate.

Comment: another thing, checking by frame counting will only work on that cam and checking by time passed will work on any cam.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try and use your method to check the time instead of the frames and see how that works. I'll either edit this question or make a new one depending on the problems I run into. Thank you for your help! @DimaMaligin